# Cordova application is showing 'old' package name in the plugins android.json file

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am running Cordova 5.x and have installed the camera plugins,

```
"installed_plugins": {
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.mytechnologies.abc"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.mytechnologies.abc"
    }
},
```

Although I should be expecting to see the package name that is currently within the config.xml (which is as follows)

```
com.mytechnologies.abc
```

Any suggestions why I am seeing my 'old' platform name and not the one in my config.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to re-install the plugins? When this error happened with me , it worked!

Comment: I seem to have do manually remove the folder (rather than use the command) and then use cordova platform add android for this to work